# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException under API Level 19

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an app, that starts except under API 19 and I get the stacktrace below.

I previously had to add to gradle's build:

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
```

from another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40490131/classnotfoundexception-didnt-find-class-on-path-dexpathlist-on-api-19/40502653) I added also the dependency

```
depenencies {
   ...
   compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
   ...
}
```

But still the app crashes at start under API19.

Can someone help ?

```
02-21 16:07:05.043 3348-3348/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory) 02-21 16:07:05.043 3348-3348/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2 02-21 16:07:19.723 3359-3359/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory) 02-21 16:07:19.723 3359-3359/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2 02-21 16:07:19.923 2015-2015/com.google.android.gms E/dalvikvm: Dex cache directory isn't writable: /data/dalvik-cache 02-21 16:07:19.923 2015-2015/com.google.android.gms E/ChimeraModuleLdr: Initialization failed for module apk com.google.android.play.games
                                                                        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.chimera.GmsModuleInitializer" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/PlayGames.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                                            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
                                                                            at csg.loadClass(:com.google.android.gms@11947030:3)
                                                                            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
                                                                            at com.google.android.gms.chimera.container.GmsModuleApi.onApkLoaded(:com.google.android.gms@11947030:1)
                                                                            at csm.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947030:88)
                                                                            at csm.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947030:35)
                                                                            at csm.a(:com.google.android.gms@11947030:118)
```

Comment: probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279008/why-am-i-getting-a-classnotfoundexception-from-play-services-lib-when-using-prog

Comment: Not related, because I get a lots of errors like this. Also facebook classes can't be found. Its something with DexPathList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html), did you either make you application extend MultiDexApplication or initialize multidex in your application class?
Like so:

*Either do this:*

Make application class extent MultiDexApplication

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

Change manifest like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

*Or this*

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(context);
     Multidex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use a custom `Application` class (e.g. `MyApplication`), after extending the `MultiDexApplication` class you still should write **your** app's class name in `AndroidManifest`. Otherwise, how will the platform understand that it should use `MyApplication`?